# Proof by induction: one of $n, n+1,\ldots,2n$ is a square

Tags: induction, solution-verification

> Show that for every positive integer $n$, one of the numbers $n, n +
> 1, n + 2, \cdots , 2n$ is the square of an integer.

here what i did. but I am doing some thing wrong here and iam not sure what.

Base Case: $n = 1$

$1, 2$ is the square of an integer, which is true since $1$ is the square of an integer.

induction step:

$(k+1)^2 \le 2k^2 + 2$

$k^2 = 2k + 1 \le 2k^2 + 2$

$k^2 - 2k + 1 \ge 0$

$(k-1)^2 \ge 0$

which is true since $(k-1)^2$ is a square, so must be nonnegative.

Comment: You have shown (*without* induction!) that for all $k\in \mathbb N$ (in fact for all $k\in\mathbb R$) the inequality $(k+1)^2\le 2k^2+2$ holds. Now tell what that has to do with the claim (say, let $k\in\mathbb N$ be minimal with $(k+1)^2>2n$, then ...).

Comment: billy: we encourage users to accept an answer to each question asked, if and when an answer is found to be helpful. You can only accept one answer per question, though. To accept an answer, simply click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept: it turns green when you click on it. ;-) (You get two reputation points for each accepted answer, too).

Answer (score 2):

You have proven the following:

> For any $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $(x+1)^2 \le 2x^2+2$.

This will come in handy later.

**Inductive Step:** Assume that one of the numbers $n,n+1,n+2,...,2n$ is a perfect square, where $n \in \{1,...,k\}$. In particular (for $n=k$), we will assume that for some $r\in \{0,...,k\}$, $k+r$ is a perfect square.

It remains to prove our claim true for $n=k+1$. That is, we must prove that one of the numbers $k+1,k+2,k+3,...,2k+2$ is a perfect square. Now by the induction hypothesis, we know that $k+r$ is a perfect square for some $r\in \{0,...,k\}$. Hence, if $r\in \{1,...,k\}$, then we are done.

It remains to prove the claim true for $r=0$. Since $k+0$ is a perfect square, we have $k=a^2$ for some positive integer $a$. The next perfect square must therefore be at $(a+1)^2$. This is where your proof comes into play. Let $x=a$. Then:
$$
k=a^2<(a+1)^2\le2a^2+2=2k+2
$$
So for the case when $r=0$, one of the integers from $k$ to $2k+2$ must be the perfect square $(a+1)^2$, as desired. This completes the induction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your argument after the line "induction step:". But maybe you meant the right thing.

We have to prove by induction that each set $$A_n:=\{n,n+1,\ldots, 2n\}\qquad(n\geq1)$$ contains a square.

The set $A_1=\{1,2\}$ contains a square.

Assume that $n\geq1$ and that $A_n$ contains a square. Then
$$A_{n+1}=A_n\cup\{2n+1,2n+2\}\setminus\{n\}$$
obviously contains a square, unless the only square in $A_n$ was the number $n=k^2$. In this case
$$n<(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1=n+\sqrt{4n}+1\leq n+\sqrt{4n+(n-1)^2}+1= 2n+2\ ,$$
which proves that $(k+1)^2\in A_{n+1}$.